# Cannot install SQL Server on a local disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, clustering

I'm installing a new instance of SQL Server, and I got this error:

```
instance directory (or command line option /instancedir) value for a cluster installation cannot be a directory on shared drive
```

It is pretty clear, and this is my situation:

I have a microsoft cluster with 3 servers. All with Windows 2012R2 installed. SQL Server is version2016 SP1.

On the first 2 servers I have some SQL Server instance in failover with dedicated storage. One of the drive is Y:

This istance (IS1) **cannot move** on server03. Also for the disc, in failover cluster manager, under *Advanced Policies* I deleted server03 from possible owners.

Now I have another disk, in server03, with letter Y. This is a **local disk**.

To configure AlwaysON I need to have some local instances on Server03, and I'd like to use this disk to have an automatic seeding.

How can I convince sql server installation Y is a local disk?

Comment: Is the storage available storage in your Failover Cluster aManager?

Comment: @StijnWynants, no, clustered disk is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you have 2 servers configured for in a FCI installation. They use shared disk which is the Y drive. You have a 3rd server that has local disk which is the Y drive.

1. Node 1 and 2 should be installed first as a FCI instance.
2. As long as the FCI is working as expected and fail overs are happening as expected between Node 1 and Node 2, Node 3 should be added to the Windows Cluster as an extra node.
3. Node 3 should have SQL server installed on it as a standalone node.
4. Enable Always On feature on Node 3 and the FCI instance
5. Node 3 should not be listed as a possible owner of FCI instance.

You should then be able to have an FCI install and a standalone install on the same windows cluster. You will be able to automatic failover between Node 1 and Node 2, with manual failover to Node 3.

I have this set up in my lab now.